# How to use regular expression with a string array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, regex

I have a string array

```
string [] ar = { "net" , "com" , "org"};
```

and I want the label writes "true" when the user enter a website example ends with a string in the array

I tried this:

```
   private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach ( string ex in ar)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(txtbox.Text, @"^(www\.)([\w]+)\.(" + ex + ")$"))
            {
                lbl.Text = "True";
            }
            else
            {
                lbl.Text = "False";
            }
        }
    }
```

When I write for example "www.google.com", the label still writes `false`. Only when I write "www.google.org" the label writes `true`.

Comment: Try `lbl.Text = ar.Any(ex => Regex.IsMatch(txtbox.Text, @"^(www\.)([\w]+)\.(" + ex + ")$"))) ? "True" : "False";` instead

Comment: `EndWith` should be really enough, regex is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using foreach loop which are completing its all ittrations, 
so when ittration is compare with your condition then remove the control from loop e.g. org at the last of array index thatswhy it found at last of the lopp ittrations, edit your code as.

```
 foreach ( string ex in ar)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(txtbox.Text, @"^(www\.)([\w]+)\.(" + ex + ")$"))
            {
                lbl.Text = "True";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                lbl.Text = "False";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to stop your `foreach` iteration as soon as you hit the first match. Or, better yet,

```
lbl.Text = ar.Any(s => Regex.IsMatch(txtbox.Text, "..." + s + "...")) ? "True" : "False"
```

Plus, be careful with timers in a WinForms applications: you can only safely use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, not `System.Threading.Timer`.